# LocalDate::of - None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: kotlin, named-parameters

In kotlin, this works:

```
LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 1)
```

However when I try to use named parameters I get the error:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
>
> public open fun of(p0: Int, p1: Month!, p2: Int): LocalDate! defined in java.time.LocalDate
>
> public open fun of(p0: Int, p1: Int, p2: Int): LocalDate! defined in java.time.LocalDate

With either:

```
LocalDate.of(year=2023, month = Month.JANUARY, dayOfMonth=1)
```

or

```
LocalDate.of(year=2023, month = 1, dayOfMonth=1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Named parameters are only possible with Kotlin-defined functions.

As `java.time.LocalDate` is a Java class, you can't use named parameters.

See [discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/what-is-the-reason-for-not-allowing-named-arguments-for-java-interop/4571).